# Can't compile CUDA driver api sample under OS X

Tags: c++, macos, cuda

I'm trying to compile code that uses nvidia cuda driver api, but compilation return following error:

```
g++ -fPIC -o exec helloWorldDriverAPI.cpp.o -lcuda
ld: library not found for -lcuda
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [exec] Error 1
```

Here is sample code that i have problem with:
https://github.com/mciancia/CUDA-Driver-api

I tried pointing libraries folder manually but it didn't work for me.

Also, i don't have any problems with compiling this code under Linux.
I'm using macbook with nvidia 750m under os x 10.10 and latest driver (6.5)

Comment: Just a stupid question: But did you install properly the CUDA **SDK**? Just having the drivers is not enough. On Linux the CUDA installation through the package manager often includes the SDK. Also as per the usual Apple conventions, CUDA may be a Framework on MacOS X, so you probably have to use something like -framework CUDA or such, instead of -lcuda.

Comment: Yeah, I installed cuda SDK, also i don't have any problems compiling samples provided by nvidia and code that uses runtime api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was answered [elsewhere](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/793575/cuda-setup-and-installation/problems-with-driver-api-on-apple-os-x/), copying the answer here to get it off the unanswered list:

You need to add the location of the library.
The LIB_CUDA variable in your Makefile should be:

```
LIB_CUDA := -L/usr/local/cuda/lib -lcuda
```